# Update one column of a table with another table column having multiple values seperated with comma

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables A, B.
A is having Expns code, Expns desc, Type
and the values of table are as below

```
Expns code| Expns Desc|Type Code
--------- | ----------|-----------
1         | A         |Bond, Public
----------|-----------|------------
2         |B          |Private,Medi
```

B table  is having columns type,typedetcode,typedetdesc
and B table having type with data Bond,public,private,med
now i want to update Typedetcode,typdedetdesc columns of B table based on the type from A table column 'type' as below.

```
Type   | TypeDetcode|Typedetdesc
------ | -----------|-----------
Bond   | 1          |A
--------------------------------
Public | 1          |A
--------------------------------
Private| 2          |B
--------------------------------
Medi   | 2          |B
```

Thanks,

Comment: please format your data and show expected result

Comment: I tried to get some format and clearity into your question, which was absolutely unclear... Hope I got your tables right... What happens if table A has got more than one row with a given type? Please add some more rows to Table A and please add a copy of Table B filled with the expected result fitting to the sample data you provide in Table A.

Comment: Hi, Can any one please help me regarding the above query. Thanks,

Comment: I have tried as below         
    Update B set TypeDetcode=Expns code,Typedetdesc=Expns Desc
    From  B Inner Join CLM_MF_EXPENSE A
   
    Where A.Type Code Like '%'+ B.TYPE + '%' but getting primary key violation error